# Retrieve UID from firebase with context consummer

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to retrieve user's ***uid*** from Firebase.
I have a context ***AuthUserContext*** which provides user's data. But I need to get it in my component ***apiRecipe*** in order to add data to a specific user.

Here's my DB:
[image: firebase data]

This is [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@m-ajestic/app-planeat).expo, it does not run, but you can see files's code about the issue:

- Recipe/apiRecipe.js
- Recipe/index.js
- Session folder for the context

I'm just starting out and I have surely misunderstood how to use a context properly.

I'm open for any advices, many thanks !

EDIT:

I want to retrieve UID from a user using AuthUserContext.

This is the code where I want to retrieve UID value:

```
const apiRecipe = WrappedComponent => (

  class HOC extends Component {
    state = {
      uid: 'userId',
      recipies: {}
    }

    componentDidMount () {
      this.loadUserId(uidUser)

      this.ref = base.syncState(`users/${this.state.uid}/recipies`, {
        context: this,
        state: 'recipies'
      })
    }

    loadUserId = uidUser => (
      this.setState({ uid: uidUser})
    )
    
    render () {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          recipiesDB={this.state.recipies}
          createRecette={this.createRecette}
          {...this.props}
        />
      )
    }
  }
)

const uidUser = (
  <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    {authUser => (
      authUser ? authUser.uid : 'Nope'
    )}
  </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
)

export default apiRecipe
```

But it does not work, state.uid gets :
[image: state wrong value]

I am doing it wrong or is there another way to retrieve uid ?

EDIT*:

This is a solution I've found to retrieve user's UID:

```
  firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      // User logged in already or has just logged in.
      this.setState({ uid: user.uid })
      this.ref = base.syncState(`users/${this.state.uid}/recipies`, {
        context: this,
        state: 'recipies'
      })
    }
  })
```

Is there a better way to achieve it ?

Comment: While a link to a reproduction is great, it is no replacement for including [the minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself too.

Comment: I did not manage to make snack.expo working. I thought it may be enough with the files's code. I've updated my question to focus on the issue and where I have it.

Comment: this could v' way easier if you used hooks

Comment: Would it be possible to have an example with hooks ?